# Laravel - diffForHumans in German

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to display the `created_at` attribute using Carbon's `diffForHumans()` in German in laravel 5.2.
`created_at` is stored in the database as: `2017-03-29 17:31:52`
**The model**

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

public static function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    Carbon::setLocale('de');
    return Carbon::parse($value, 'Europe/Berlin')->diffForHumans();
}
```

`dd($value);` returns `"2017-03-29 17:31:52"`.
**The view**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <small>{{ $post->getCreatedAtAttribute($post->created_at) }}</small>
@endforeach
```

**The error**

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (vor 3 Tagen) at
>   position 0 (v): The timezone could not be found in the database

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: what's the value of `$post->created_at` ? it seems that the issue within it

Comment: `dd(Carbon::parse('2017-03-29 17:31:52', 'Europe/Berlin')->diffForHumans());` outputs : "vor 3 Tagen", so i think that there are an issue with passing the `$post->created_at` in the view file

Comment: @hassan You are completely right!! `$post->created_at` returns `3 days ago` not `2017-03-29 17:31:52`! Although the value in the database for `created_at` is `2017-03-29 17:31:52` and not `3 days ago`.

Comment: you may delete the question then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a German translation I used this customization in the AppServiceProvider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Localization Carbon

        \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    }
}
```

With this setting the data is displayed: `vor 3 Tagen` instead of `3 days ago`.